# CMake not able to find Qt4

Tags: cmake, qt4

I'm working on a project using PCL (point cloud library) for which I need to configure some code files using CMake. But some of these files aren't getting configured and the error CMake shows for those files is "Qt4 not found". I already have Qt 4.8 installed and this is the only Qt version I have. Also, for some of the other files, CMake used Qt without showing any error. And when I run qmake.exe, it shows "Qt : Untested windows version 6.2 detected". And for all the Qt5 related entries, CMake shows "NOT FOUND". Have I installed the correct version of Qt? And how can I get CMake to detect Qt4?

I'm using windows 8.1 64bit

When I typed qmake -v in command prompt, I got this -

Qt: Untested Windows version 6.2 detected!

QMake version 2.01a

Using Qt version 4.8.0 in C:\Qt\4.8.0\lib

Comment: Fix your tags, is the problem qt or more specific qt4? Or is it a plain CMake question? How is cmake-gui related? Beside that: I don't even get your question. What's the link to qmake? What have you done and what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score -1):

1. `cmake` to find `Qt` users `qmake`, so if you run it not from command line,
   make sure that global environment variable PATH set to proper value, so `cmake` can find `qmake`
2. `cmake` cache libraries search results, bad results also. Because of that, if it can find some library, you install it, then rerun `cmake` it can show again "library not found" message, even if your setup is corrret. So make sure to remove `CMakeCache.txt` before rerun `cmake`.